# When do I use EndOnDemandTransfer() in Azure Diagnostics?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-diagnostics

Azure Diagnostics provides [`RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager.EndOnDemandTransfer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.management.roleinstancediagnosticmanager.endondemandtransfer.aspx) method which I don't quite get. If I just call `BeginOnDemandTransfer()` then `GetActiveTransfers()` returns a non-empty collection at all times and my code doesn't know when to stop waiting for the transfer to complete.

Looks like I have to call `EndOnDemandTransfer()`, but MSDN is not very clear about it.

When do I use `EndOnDemandTranfer()` in Azure Diagnostics?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the **EndOnDemandTransfer** method after the on-demand transfer completed. When starting the on-demand transfer, you pass the **OnDemandTransferOptions** to the method:

```
var options = new OnDemandTransferOptions();
options.NotificationQueueName = "on-demand-notifications";
...

manager.BeginOnDemandTransfer(DataBufferName.Logs, options);
```

As you can see from the code sample you can set the **NotificationQueueName** on the **OnDemandTransferOptions** class. This is the queue that will receive a message once the on-demand transfer completes. You'll need to monitor the queue, read the message and finally call the **EndOnDemandTranfer** method with the **RequestId** you'll find in the message.

This is how such a message looks like:

```
<OnDemandTransfers>
  <Logs>
    <NotificationQueueName>wad-transfer</NotificationQueueName>
    <LevelFilter>Undefined</LevelFilter>
    <From>2009-12-10T11:27:15.1376953Z</From>
    <To>2009-12-10T11:32:15.1376953Z</To>
    <RequestId>7352b663-ba11-413a-8db0-bca889ea84df</RequestId>
  </Logs>
</OnDemandTransfers>
```

Read more about this on Neil's blog: http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/diagnostics-management-in-windows-azure/

Answer (score 0):

Sandrino is correct, but I will add another perspective.  You should in theory get notified to a queue (if specified) when starting the OnDemand transfer.  However, I have found that setting a Scheduled transfer is easier.  Polling a queue and correctly calling EndOnDemandTransfer is a bit of a hassle.

Setting a 1 min transfer interval means it will start and continue every 1 min.  Once you get the data you need, just turn it off by setting it back to 0.  IMHO, easier than dealing with OnDemand.

More Info:
http://dunnry.com/blog/2012/04/16/GettingDiagnosticsDataFromWindowsAzure.aspx

Comment: How do I know I've "got the data I need"? I always thought it is just a continuous process of getting a buffered dump of whatever the process outputs, so it goes on until the role stops.

Comment: You have same problem in OnDemand case.  If you know the time range of what you want, great, otherwise you need to continually pull until you see what you were looking for.  Remember, scheduled transfer pulls all buffered data off box, not just a specific time range.

Comment: Yes, I know that all data is pushed into the storage. And my goal is to just push all the buffered data into the storage so that data between the previous push and my code leaving `RoleEntryPoint.OnStop()` is not lost. So what do I do? Whatever small period I specify for the scheduled transfer I still risk losing some of the latest data and that data might contain something that aids debugging some shutdown issue.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned the case where you are trying to compensate for a failing or scaling away instance.  Basically, you are at the mercy of how fast it can transfer.  Given you have 5 mins max on graceful shutdown, don't count on it to finish.  If you have a non-hardware failure, the same instance usually restarts, which gives you the buffered data on restart.  If you have hardware issue or don't get same VM, all bets are off.

Comment: Okay, so what do I do then? Just set the interval to something like one minute?